# File writing with blob data

Tags: java, file, blob

I am reading the blob data from Oracle database & writing it to a text file. I have two column in my database called Number & system. I have 100 counts in my table. But only the last row is writing in my text row. below is the code I have tried.

```
rs =stmt.executeQuery("select Number, system from system");
Blob lob = null;


while (rs.next()) {
  String RECID = rs.getString(1);
  System.out.println("Number"+ Number);

  lob=rs.getBlob("system");
  byte[] bdata = lob.getBytes(1, (int) lob.length());
  String text = new String(bdata);
  System.out.println("text"+ text);

  System.out.println("rs value"+ lob);
  String test=null;
  test=RECID+":"+text;
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/DataRead/system.txt");
  DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
  dos.writeBytes(test);

  dos.close();
}
}
catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```

In text file i am getting 100th record only other 99 rows are not writing.

Comment: You reopen the output file on each iteration, most certainly clearing the previous version.

Comment: Thanks Alexis, Kindly advice how to open the output file for each iteartion

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing existing text each time in your while loop.

Try this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/DataRead/system.txt");
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
while (rs.next()) {
    String RECID = rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println("Number"+ Number);
    lob=rs.getBlob("system");
    byte[] bdata = lob.getBytes(1, (int) lob.length());
    String text = new String(bdata);
    System.out.println("text"+ text);

    System.out.println("rs value"+ lob);
    String test=null;
    test=RECID+":"+text;

    dos.writeBytes(test+"\n");
}
dos.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Bhushan, But all the data's are writing in a single line. how to enable \n after each line

Comment: @user2742540 You can use `\n` for new line. I have edited the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line in your code

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/DataRead/system.txt");
```

With:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/DataRead/system.txt", true);
```